# Property of SKEmitterNode file accessible through "dot-syntax"?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a SpriteKit game using Swift. In this game I use an SKEmitterNode to show a fire. Sometimes raindrops hits the fire and I would like it to be smoke instead. I'm thinking of using a property observer that I could change as such contact occurs. The property observer would then change `emitter.fileNamed`. However SKEmitterNode has no such thing as `.fileNamed` or `.file`. The way files are declared are `let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Fire")`. Is there a way to get around this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: SKEmitterNode particles do not have physics bodies so you will not be able to register a contact message for a rain drop hitting a flame.

Comment: yes but i have a spriteNode which i am hiding that does that detecting stuff. so when it hits the sprite node i want the emitter to change.

Comment: Are the rain drops individual sprite nodes?

Comment: yes they are individual sprite nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're looking for is `particleTexture`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/particleTexture

you can assign an SKTexture here with your image and the particles will change to that image.

Comment: Thanks. I think it´s the closest one can get. Needs a little more code but again, thank you very much for pointing that out.